# TCP -- acknowledgement

Tags: tcp

The 32-bit acknowledgement field, say x, on the TCP header 
tells the other host that "I received all the bytes up until and including x-1, 
now expecting
the bytes from x and on". In this case, the receiver may have received some 
further bytes, say x+100 through x+180, 
but it hasn't yet received x-th byte yet.

Is there a case that, although the receiver hasn't received 
x through x+100 bytes but received the bytes say x+100 through x+180, 
the receiver is acknowledging that it received x+180?

One resource I read indicates the acknowledgement of bytes received despite a gap in the earlier bytes. 
However, every other source tells

"acknowledgement of x tells all bytes up until x-1 are received".

Are there any exceptional cases? I'm looking to verify this.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by TCP option called SACK.

Here, client can say through a duplicate ACK that it has only up to particular packet number 2 (sequence number of packet) in order and append SACK(Selective Acknowledgement) option for the range of contiguous packets received like packets numbered 4 to 5 (sequence number). This in turn shall enable the server to retransmit only the packets(3 sequence number) that were not received by the client.

Provided below an extract from RFC 2018 : TCP Selective Acknowledgement Options

> The SACK option is to be sent by a data receiver to inform the data
>   sender of non-contiguous blocks of data that have been received and
>   queued.  The data receiver awaits the receipt of data (perhaps by
>   means of retransmissions) to fill the gaps in sequence space between
>   received blocks.  When missing segments are received, the data
>   receiver acknowledges the data normally by advancing the left window
>   edge in the Acknowledgement Number Field of the TCP header.  The SACK 
>   option does not change the meaning of the Acknowledgement Number
>   field.

Comment: do you know off hand how this is managed in the TCP header? for the acknowledgement, the header only has the ACK flag to work for the plain ACK. how does SACK go into the header?

Comment: It is an optional header field of TCP. TCP has provision for optional header fields which in-turn are identified by an option kind field. SACK is one of the TCP optional header field of kind 5.  Also, Note that SACK uses 2 TCP options. The first one is used at the time of session establishment where the client shall say it is willing to receive SACK options via SYN by sending the SACK-permitted option to server.  
The second one will be the SACK option itself which is sent in established TCP connection once permission has been given by SACK-permitted.

Comment: TCP sequence numbers are byte ranges, not packet numbers.

Answer (score 2):

From the TCP RFC at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.txt:

> 3.3.  Sequence Numbers
>
> A fundamental notion in the design is that every octet of data sent 
>   over a TCP connection has a sequence number.  Since every octet is
>   sequenced, each of them can be acknowledged.  The acknowledgment 
>   mechanism employed is cumulative so that an acknowledgment of sequence
>   number X indicates that all octets up to but not including X have been
>   received.

That seems pretty clear to me, the sequence number stops at the first missing data.

Comment: to me too. however - the source indicating otherwise is a reputable one.

Comment: This is from the TCP standard. There is no more reputable source for how TCP is implemented. Feel free to go read it, it's not overly difficult to understand if you have a general idea of how TCP works. I've worked on network appliances, and I've been into the area of the Linux kernel that deals with ACK calculation and I have never seen anything that would allow for an ACK to cover a missed packet. There's no mechanism to communicate back to the peer which packet was missed other than the ACK number.